# Another Version of the Quadratic Residue Law

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I'm trying to show that if $a>0$ is an integer with $p,q\nmid a$, $p,q$ odd primes, and $q\neq p$ a prime such that $p≡\pm q \pmod{4a}$, then $(a/p)=(a/q)$. Here is my proof of this theorem:

By Gauss's Lemma, we have that $(a/p)=(-1)^{\mu}$, where $\mu$ is the number of least positive residues of the set $\lbrace a, 2a, 3a,\cdots,\frac{p-1}{2}a\rbrace$ and $(a/q)=(-1)^{\mu^{\prime}}$, where $\mu^{\prime}$ is the number of least positive residues of the set $\lbrace a, 2a, 3a,\cdots,\frac{q-1} {2}a\rbrace$. Then $\mu=\frac{p-1}{2}-[\frac{p}{2a}]$ and $\mu^{\prime}=\frac{q-1}{2}-[\frac{q}{2a}]$, where $[x]$ is the floor function of $x$. Now, I want to show that given $p\equiv \pm q \pmod{4a}$, then $(a/p)=(a/q)$, so it suffices to prove that $\mu\equiv \mu^{\prime}\pmod 2$. If $p\equiv  q \pmod{4a}$, then $p=4at+ q$, for some $t \in \mathbb{Z}$. So
\begin{equation}
\mu=\frac{p-1}{2}-\bigg[\frac{p}{2a}\bigg]=\frac{4at+ q-1}{2}-\bigg[\frac{4at +q}{2a}\bigg]=2at+\frac{ q- 1}{2}-2at-\bigg[ \frac{q}{2a}\bigg]=\frac{ q-1}{2}-\bigg[ \frac{q }{2a}\bigg]=\mu^{\prime}
\end{equation}
If $p\equiv -q \pmod{4a}$, then $p=4at-q$, and so
\begin{equation}
\mu=\frac{p-1}{2}-\bigg[\frac{p}{2a}\bigg]=\frac{4at-q-1}{2}-\bigg[\frac{4at -q}{2a}\bigg]=2at-\frac{ q+ 1}{2}-2at-\bigg[ \frac{-q}{2a}\bigg]=-\frac{ q+1}{2}-\bigg[ \frac{-q }{2a}\bigg].
\end{equation}
We now need to show that
\begin{equation}
\frac{q-1}{2}-\bigg[\frac{q}{2a}\bigg]\equiv -\frac{ q+1}{2}-\bigg[ \frac{-q }{2a}\bigg] \pmod 2
\end{equation}
or that
\begin{equation}
\frac{q-1}{2}-\bigg[\frac{q}{2a}\bigg]+\frac{ q+1}{2}+\bigg[ \frac{-q }{2a}\bigg] 
\end{equation}
is even.
Now, note that
\begin{equation}
\frac{q-1}{2}-\bigg[\frac{q}{2a}\bigg]+\frac{ q+1}{2}+\bigg[ \frac{-q }{2a}\bigg] =q+\bigg[ \frac{-q }{2a}\bigg]-\bigg[\frac{q}{2a}\bigg]
\end{equation}
The integer
\begin{equation}
\bigg[ \frac{-q }{2a}\bigg]-\bigg[\frac{q}{2a}\bigg]
\end{equation}
is odd, because since $b/2a$ is not an integer, then $[q/2a]+[-q/2a]=1$, and thus $[-q/2a]-[q/2a]=2[-q/2a]+1$. Thus $q+[-q/2a]-[q/2a]$ is even, and $\mu\equiv \mu^{\prime}\pmod{2}$. We conclude that $(a/p)=(a/q)$.

Please correct if I did something wrong, or if you can find a much easier way to prove the theorem.